# Integrating wordpress with moodle

Tags: php, wordpress, moodle

I am trying to integrate wordpress with moodle.
I want a user to get logged into wordpress when he is logging into moodle.
Problem : To use wordpress login function wp-load.php in included that loads all the wordpress functions.Some functions are common in both wordpress and moodle.This is creating issues.
Someone please suggest a way to achieve this.
Regards
Bhavna Singh

Answer (score 0):

dont change the core. You can hook the login-methods with actions and filters to redirect the login-request.

If you want to sign in to an external site, use cURL.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the external tool in Moodle

http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/External_tool

Answer (score 0):

There is one plugin for integration between Wordpress and Moodle
"Edwiser Bridge" https://edwiser.org which also provides an extension "Single Sign on" which provides end users with an option to enter a single username and password on the WordPress website and gain access on WordPress as well as Moodle simultaneously. https://edwiser.org/bridge/extensions/single-sign-on/